# Reduce time to run multiple group by in Python

Tags: python

I want to run multiple (1000's) of different combinations of classification variables as "group_by" levels and return the sum of other metrics across these groups.

I have written code to run this in pandas using groupby and it works, but takes some time, using numpy I can increase speed for a single groupby but timings are slower when running groupby on multiple dimensions.

Is there a faster way than pandas to compute the required aggregations?

I have a workign solution in pandas, I have replicated the single level aggregation (one classification variable) with slightly faster speed using numpy:

```py
att_data=df.loc[:,'class1'].values.astype(int)
weight_data=df.loc[:,'aggvar'].values
out=np.bincount(att_data, weights=weight_data)
```

when I try and replicate this across multiple dimensions the numpy solution is slower than pandas aggregation (presumably because I'm spending more effort creating the vectors required):

```py
att_data1=df.loc[:,'class1'].values.astype(int)
att_data2=df.loc[:,'class2'].values.astype(int)
weight_data=df.loc[:,'aggvar'].values
test_combin=np.column_stack((att_data1, att_data2))
nouse, att_comb_data=np.unique(test_combin, return_inverse=True, axis=0)
outi=np.bincount(att_comb_data, weights=weight_data)
```

This code works but I would prefer to speed it up

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 5)),100*np.random.random_sample(size=(100,1))),axis=1), columns=list(('class1','class2','class3','class4','class5','aggvar')))

agg_list=['class1','class2','class3','class4','class5']

for agg1 in agg_list:
    for agg2 in agg_list:
        if agg1==agg2:
            out_ag=df.groupby(agg1).agg({'aggvar':np.sum})
        else:
            out_ag=df.groupby([agg1,agg2]).agg({'aggvar':np.sum})
```

Expected result is combined aggregations at all combined levels of the classification variables, as illustrated below (i can construct but want to speed the base aggregation):

```
1_class 2nd_class   1_class_val 2nd_class_val   sum(aggvar)
class1          1               50125
class1          2               96397
class1          3               94886
class1  class2      1       1       12531
class1  class2      1       2       17544
class1  class2      1       3       10025
class1  class2      1       4       10025
class1  class2      1       1       37593
class1  class2      1       2       12531
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize your grouping operation. Concrete examples of this can be found [here](https://jacquespeeters.github.io/2017/08/21/parallel-pandas-groupby/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/dmyersturnbull/dff552ad719943b1362d005eb86744ec).

Comment: What about sketiching out the core ideas in some code here too?